# Python. concurrent.futures

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have an async main() that starts the gui build using tkinter and I would like it to fetch_data from an api while gui is building.

As of now I have an issue as the gui finished but it does not start the fetch_data.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import tkinter as tk
from fetch_data import fetch_data
from Filters import DataFilter
import json
import asyncio
from tkinter import filedialog
from FileProcessor import FileProcessor
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

async def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Assets report")
    submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate the Report", state=tk.DISABLED, command=save_selected_dates, bg = "white")
    
    #gui setting here......

    def check_mana_status(root, data_future, submit_button):
        if data_future.done():
            submit_button["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        else:
            root.after(100, lambda: check_mana_status(root, data_future, submit_button))


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        data_future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, fetch_data)

    check_mana_status(root, data_future, submit_button)

    root.mainloop()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The fetch_data file looks like this:

```py
from FileProcessor import FileProcessor
from Filters import DataFilter
import requests
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch_data():
    url_exp = "https://example.url"
    try:
        print('start calls')
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            get_data(url_exp, headers),
            get_data(url_exp, headers),
            get_data(url_exp, headers),
            get_data(url_exp, headers)
            )

        response_data_co, response_data_ci, response_data_cr, response_data_hw = results

        print('ready')

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error:", e)

    return [response_data_co + response_data_cr + response_data_ci, response_data_hw]
```

Comment: please fix your code indentation: it is broken as it is, and indentation is _part_ of Python syntax which conveys the structure of your program, it is not an optional thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It got moved during copy-paste.